# How To Add Multiple Images To An Image view

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to have multiple images within a master Image view ,as the background so when the master imageview move all the other images within it will move to  but its only displaying one image (whichever ones further down). How would i fix this or is there a more simpler method

My Code

```
    masterview = new ImageView(tree);
    masterview = new ImageView(imgbg);
    masterview.setLayoutX(0);
    masterview.setLayoutY(0);

    root.getChildren().addAll(masterview);
```

Comment: An `ImageView` can only contain one `Image`. Use multiple `ImageView`s in some appropriate layout pane.

Answer (score 0):

Since an ImageView can only refer to one image, you can create a different class which contains an array or dynamic structure to hold multiple ImageView objects. For an array and dynamic structure, an add method which creates a new object when it is called will work well.

You can also create the data structure in the same class. However, if the data structure is in a different class the code will be cleaner and future methods to modify multiple ImageView components will be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Like what James_D said, use multiple `ImageView` and wrap it in a suitable pane.

For your case, `StackPane` looks appropriate.

```
final StackPane container = new StackPane();
final ImageView mainImageView = new ImageView();
final ImageView bgImageView = new ImageView();

container.getChildren().addAll(bgImageView, mainImageView);

root.getChildren().add(container);
```

As both `ImageView` overlaps each other, if the image at the top doesn't have transparent areas, the image below it will not be visible.